# How to create a J1939 ID that have a PGN = 0x130?

Tags: automotive, can, network, j1708

I'm trying to create a J1939 message with a PGN equal to 130.
But I couldn't determine how the ID is going to look like in order to get that exact PGN.

Can you please share a suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Isnt it just R=0, DP=0, PF=0x00, PS=0x82? (assuming you mean decimal 130)

Comment: @BeB00 , No can you give the full 29-bit identifier then. ie: with 0x008200 would give PGN = 0x00 as from http://alumni.cs.ucsb.edu/~savior/convert-j1939-id-to-pgn.php

Comment: That calculator wont give you a PGN of 130. If that calculator is correct, then a value of 130 isnt possible. The calculator wont accept a PF of 0, which is required to get PGN=130

Comment: Ignoring the calculator, the value 0x00008200 will give you the correct PGN, but that may not be a valid ID. Why do you want a PGN of 130?

Comment: @BeB00 sorry it seems to be 0x130 in Hex. What do you think ?

Comment: In that case it might be 0x00000980, but I dont think these calculators are calculating the PGN properly, or else you cant have a PGN that low. It seems that the PGN always has 6 trailing 0's

Comment: I used another tool CANdb++ and it gave me the same results for 0x00000980 gave me pgn = 0x00 so they cannot be wrong :(

Comment: Then I guess you cant have a PGN that low. Again, why do you want one?

Answer (score 1):

if 130 is in hex PGN=0x130, it means PDU Format is 1 and PDU Specific is 30, it depends on your option if your priority is 1 and Source Address is 1 your ID is 0x4013001.
search j1939 frame on google for details